# Excel Found unreadable content. View from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook) when trying open excel file. Changes with Apache-POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I know it's famous issue, but I want to try ask you again.

When I am trying to open .xlsx file I am facing with a problem:

"Excel Found unreadable content bla bla bla".

And then when I am open the file, confirming the warning, I see that file looks fine. And I have next Excel log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error051320_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'D:\Temp\ON\output\validationtaxreport_20170503_171253.xlsx'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: View from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I am changing file using apache-POI 3.5-FINAL version. I know it's pretty old version of library, but I can't change it unfortunately.

I am using .xlsx(.xls works fine) file with existing worksheets. They are almost empty, the are carrying some template headers.

Issue appears when I am changing this worksheets or deleting non-using of them.

If before clear I will using empty workbook file - it works fine. Somthing happening when I am deleting sheets after all changes. I am not deleting them in procces, only after all changes.

Some notes:

- I don't have any sheets with more than 31 characters in the name.
- It works fine with .xls file
- I am not using sorting at my code
- File seems fine after I confirm the error.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: To process .xlsx files you need poi-ooxml dependency

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to something recent?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: because my program works normally with .xls file, I tried to open it and save in .xlsx format. And it helped me.